# How can I use vector graphics for the different states of a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Can someone provide sample code in Swift for implementing a custom UIButton using different vector graphics (UIBazierPath) for each of the different states of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass UIButton then draw based on UIControlState. For example:

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override var selected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override var highlighted:Bool{
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
       if self.state == .Selected
       {
            //Do complex vector drawing for selected state
            let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 15.0)
            UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
            roundRect.fill()
        }
        else if self.state == .Normal
       {
            //Do complex vector drawing for normal state
            let rect = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
            UIColor.redColor().setFill()
            rect.fill()
        }
        else if self.state == .Highlighted
       {
            //Do complex vector drawing for highlighted state
            let roundRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: 15.0)
            UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
            roundRect.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

Shows red rect when norma, and green rounded rect when selected or highlighted.

Comment: Thanks @beyowulf . Do you happen to know how to resize a bezier shape in IB? I can't set the correct height.

Comment: Set UIViewContentMode to .Redraw and either set it's frame or add a height constraint and set it to desired value.